# Spring @Scheduled not running on fixedDelayString interval

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

We have a Spring Boot application running in a Kubernetes cluster.
We are using Spring's `@Scheduled` annotation in order to Schedule different jobs.
At the moment we have 9 Schedulers, of which 5 are running every 30 minutes, two are running every 10 minutes, and 2 are running every 500ms.
We are seeing strange behavior with the ones running every 500ms, we have added logging and execution time - but it seems that these 500ms are not running properly - there is a gap of few seconds sometimes between executions

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "500")
public void executeJob() {
 // DO SOMETHING
  logger.info("Finished scheduler, that took {} milliseconds",(endTime - startTime));
}
```

We have setup the property `spring.task.scheduling.pool.size` to 20, which means that 20 threads can be running to execute the scheduled jobs (by default it is 1).
Also before starting the debugging, we have increased the CPU resources from 1 CPU core to 2.5 CPU cores, and again to 4 CPU cores but we are seeing same behavior.

Here are some logs that are appearing in our logging system

```
May 02 18:15:19.749service-client-Finished scheduler, that took 0 milliseconds
May 02 18:15:02.071service-client-Finished scheduler, that took 1 milliseconds
May 02 18:14:57.040service-client-Finished scheduler, that took 1 milliseconds
May 02 18:14:56.039service-client-Finished scheduler, that took 1 milliseconds
May 02 18:14:55.039service-client-Finished scheduler, that took 1 milliseconds
May 02 18:14:54.039service-client-Finished scheduler, that took 1 milliseconds
```

NOTE:
The actual Scheduled classes have 2 beans each (which means 4 beans per pod) that are running the 500ms jobs. The are instantiated via `@Bean` annotation.